# Converting PyTorch to ONNX model increases file size for ALBert

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx, quantization, onnxruntime

Goal: Use this [Notebook](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-inference-examples/blob/main/quantization/notebooks/bert/Bert-GLUE_OnnxRuntime_quantization.ipynb) to perform quantisation on **albert-base-v2** model.

Kernel: `conda_pytorch_p36`.

---

Outputs in **Sections 1.2 & 2.2** show that:

- converting vanilla **BERT** from **PyTorch to ONNX** stays the **same size**, `417.6 MB`.
- **Quantization models are smaller** than vanilla BERT, PyTorch `173.0 MB` and ONNX `104.8 MB`.

However, when running **ALBert**:

- PyTorch and ONNX model **sizes are different**.
- Quantized model sizes are **bigger** than vanilla.

I *think* this is the reason for **poorer model performance of both Quantization** methods of ALBert, compared to vanilla ALBert.

PyTorch:

```
Size (MB): 44.58906650543213
Size (MB): 22.373255729675293
```

ONNX:

```
ONNX full precision model size (MB): 341.64233207702637
ONNX quantized model size (MB): 85.53886985778809
```

---

**Why might exporting ALBert from PyTorch to ONNX increase model size, but not for BERT?**

Please let me know if there's anything else I can add to post.

Comment: My [Git Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/10340)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

ALBert model has shared weights among layers. `torch.onnx.export` outputs the weights to different tensors, which causes the model size to grow larger.

A number of Git Issues have been marked Solved regarding this *phenomena*.

The most common solution is to **remove shared weights**, that is to remove tensor arrays that contain the exact same values.

---

### Solutions

Section "Removing shared weights" in [onnx_remove_shared_weights.ipynb](https://github.com/hetpandya/onnx-shared-weights-remove/blob/main/onnx_remove_shared_weights.ipynb).

[Pseudo-code](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/issues/3278#issuecomment-781948998):

```py
from onnxruntime.transformers.onnx_model import OnnxModel
model=onnx.load(path)
onnx_model=OnnxModel(model)
count = len(model.graph.initializer)
same = [-1] * count
for i in range(count - 1):
  if same[i] >= 0:
    continue
  for j in range(i+1, count):
     if has_same_value(model.graph.initializer[i], model.graph.initializer[j]):
    same[j] = i

for i in range(count):
   if same[i] >= 0:
        onnx_model.replace_input_of_all_nodes(model.graph.initializer[i].name, model.graph.initializer[same[i]].name)

onnx_model.update_graph()
onnx_model.save_model_to_file(output_path)
```

[Source of both solutions](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/51343#issuecomment-782030861)